# Русификация консоли Freebsd?

Tags: консоль, freebsd

Моя главная проблема в том, что я не могу настроить русскую консоль во Freebsd.
Версия 10.3 Свежеустановленная. Там при установке можно выбрать keymap, но получаются кракозябры как-то все криво. Вот ставишь Ghostbsd и там уже все четко в консоли) Нужен только русский и английский и переключение между ними. Официальная документация.. хэндбук не особо помогла.
Помогите)Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В    /etc.rc.conf добавить

```
font8x16="cp866-8x16"
scrnmap="koi8-r2cp866"
keymap="ru.koi8-r"
```

после этого выбрать Keymap

Answer (score 2):

1) Сперва добавить в /etc/login.conf

```
utf8|UTF-8 Users Accounts:\
  :charset=UTF-8:\
  :lang=en_US.UTF-8:\
  :tc=default:

utf8r|Russian UTF-8 Users Accounts:\
  :charset=UTF-8:\
  :lang=ru_RU.UTF-8:\
  :tc=default:
```

2) Выполнить:

```
cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf
pw usermod -n root -L utf8
pw usermod -n ваш_логин -L utf8r
```

3) Выкачать шрифты terminus на выбор в каталог /usr/share/vt/fonts/:

[image: пример шрифтов]

[ter-u16.fnt](http://unix1.jinr.ru/~lavr/vt/ter-u16.fnt)

```
cd /usr/share/vt/fonts/
fetch http://majestio.info/stuff/ter-u16.fnt
```

4) Прописать нужный шрифт в /etc/rc.conf, и за одно переключение Рус/Лат по Ctrl-Shift:

```
font8x16="ter-u16.fnt"
keymap="ru.win"
```

5) Прописать в /boot/loader.conf:

```
kern.vty=vt
```

6) Проверить поддержку UTF-8 в ядре (при необходимости пересобрать ядро):

```
options         TEKEN_UTF8
```

7) Перезагрузиться. Получим для рута en_US.UTF-8, для пользователя ru_RU.UTF-8